# Shoved EPPlus in C# windowform cant get Autofill value In excel file

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms-designer, epplus

**EPPlus in C# windowform cant get Autofill value In excel file.

Bug Message:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.Value.get returned null.

Here my code Pls help me**

```
 private void btn_Import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        List<UserInfo> userList = new List<UserInfo>();
        try
        {
            //Open File Excel
            var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("Thang1.xlsx"));
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    int j = 1;
                    string SoCC = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value==null? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i,j++].Value.ToString();
                    string Ngay = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();
                    string ThongTin = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();
                    string PhanLoai = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();
                    string Hoten = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value;
                    string Phi = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value;
                    UserInfo user = new UserInfo()
                    {
                        SoccHS = SoCC,
                        NgayHS = Ngay,
                        ThongTinHS = ThongTin,
                        PhanLoaiHS = PhanLoai,
                        HotenHS = Hoten,
                        PhiHS = Phi,
                    };
                    userList.Add(user);



                }
                catch (Exception exe)
                {
                    
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        }
        dtg_Excel.DataSource = userList;
    }
```

Comment: Using `j++` is adding 1 to `j`… So the line of code… `string SoCC = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value==null? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i,j++].Value.ToString();` …will be adding two (2) to `j`… are you sure this is what you want to do? Also, This Is using two different cells.

Comment: In other words, the code “checks” cell one’s (1) value, if it is Not `null` then the code returns the value in cell two (2)?  I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: Excel file having some column with auto fill value So my code can't get that value cell. Ex: this line string SoCC = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value==null? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i,j++].Value.ToString(); cant return Autofill value cell.

Comment: I am guessing you do not understand my previous comments. This has nothing to do with `Autofill` values. From your last comment… _”Ex: this line string SoCC = worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value==null? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[i,j++].Value.ToString();”_ … this line of code is using TWO (2) different cells… `worksheet.Cells[i, j++].Value==null` … is one cell… and … `worksheet.Cells[i,j++].Value.ToString();` is a DIFFERENT cell.

Comment: The code is improperly using `j++.` Every time `j++` is used `j` is increment by 1. You should use `j` WITHOUT the `++` in the worksheet indexes and increment `j++` after each line of code. Trace the code and look at the `j` variable you will see what I mean.

Comment: I shoved my problem . I change  it to SoccHS = workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Text  not ruturn Value.
Thank for ur , guy